# C++ Defining a public class method that accepts an instance of itself as a parameter

Tags: c++, class, methods, parameters

I'm defining a public class method that accepts an instance of that class as a parameter, but I'm not sure how to do it.  Here's what I think it should look like:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class Circle {

    private:
        double radius;
        
    public:
        string display(Circle);
};

string Circle::display(Circle c){
    return "The radius is: " radius; 
}
```

1. Did I pass the parameter correctly when defining the method inside the class?
2. If I'm trying to display the radius as a string when calling the method, did I enter the correct return value/syntax?

Comment: Have you tried compiling and running the program? Also mention the results of doing that.

Comment: "did I enter the correct ... syntax?" Your compiler will answer this for you. In this case, in the negative, since `"The radius is: " radius` is not a valid expression.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter should be passed by `const` reference, not by value, thus avoiding a copy being made of the passed object:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Circle {

    private:
        double radius;
        
    public:
        string display(const Circle &);
};

string Circle::display(const Circle &c) {
   ...
}
```

However, your method is not using the parameter for anything, so either:

- display the `radius` of the passed object:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Circle {

    private:
        double radius;
        
    public:
        Circle(double radius);

        string display(const Circle &);
};

Circle::Circle(double radius) : radius(radius) { }

string Circle::display(const Circle &c) {
   return "The radius is: " + to_string(c.radius); 
}

int main() {
    Circle c{123.45};
    cout << c.display(c);
}
```

In which case, your method is not doing anything with the object it is called on, so it should be made `static`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Circle {

    private:
        double radius;
        
    public:
        Circle(double radius);

        static string display(const Circle &);
};

Circle::Circle(double radius) : radius(radius) { }

string Circle::display(const Circle &c) {
   return "The radius is: " + to_string(c.radius); 
}

int main() {
    Circle c{123.45};
    cout << Circle::display(c);
}
```

- get rid of the parameter altogether and instead display the `radius` of the object that the method is called on:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Circle {

    private:
        double radius;
        
    public:
        Circle(double radius);

        string display() const;
};

Circle::Circle(double radius) : radius(radius) { }

string Circle::display() const {
   return "The radius is: " + to_string(radius); 
}

int main() {
    Circle c{123.45};
    cout << c.display();
}
```